# Can I tell the Rust compiler to ignore warnings only on files matching a specific name?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using a library that generates a bunch of code for me, and it's often quite eager in generating methods that I'm not using yet. This results in a bunch of noisy warnings when building my project.

The script generates plain old .rs files throughout my codebase, which I then import and call, much like normal code:

```
mod autogen_code; 
pub use self::autogen_code::*;
```

I can't use `#![allow(unused_whatever)]` on the generated code, because when I rebuild my project, the generation script runs again and any changes would be gone. These files are `.gitignore`'d, and have big comments at the top saying "This is all auto-generated. Do not touch."

I don't want to allow unused stuff across my whole project, so placing `#![allow(unused_whatever)]` at the top of my crate is also a non-starter.

The good thing is that the generated files all have a predictable name, so what I'm hoping is that there's a way to tell cargo/rustc not to emit warnings for files matching a particular file name. Is this possible?

Comment: @Shepmaster The script that generates it places plain old `.rs` files throughout your codebase, which you then import and call, much like normal code.

Comment: I import it like `mod autogen_code; pub use self::autogen_code::*;`. And I mean, technically yes I can open the generated file and edit it, but when I rebuild my project, the generation script runs again and my changes are gone. These files are `.gitignore`'d, and have big comments at the top saying `This is all auto-generated. Do not touch.`

Comment: offload generated code to a new crate? you can have more than one crate in a workspace which may be useful

Comment: If you import it like `mod autogen_code` - simply use `allow` on it?

Comment: Thanks @VictorPolevoy, I didn't realise I could use `allow` on a `mod`!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you cannot apply lints using a filename pattern.

Instead, you can...

- Instead of using `!#[allow(...)]` *inside* the file, use `#[allow(...)]` on the `mod` declaration:

  ```
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    mod autogen;
  ```
- Modify the generation step to change the files. For example, instead of running `library-generator foo.input`, run `library-generator foo.input && sed -i '' '1s/^/#![allow(whatever)]/' myfile.rs`. You can also do this in pure Rust. Since "the generated files all have a predictable name" you could also find all the files this way and perform this transformation. Now the transform will be applied every time you regenerate the files.
- Modify the generator itself to add an option to either restrict what functions are output or to add the `allow` setting. If you experience the problem, it's likely others do as well. Might as well fix it for everyone.
- In certain cases, you can create a "shim" module that does whatever you need to do and then `include!` the real code. This is kind of nasty though:

  ```
    #![allow(...)]

    include!("autogen_real.rs");
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a few options to explore :)